# Firestore Security on Path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Using Firestore Security rules, I was wondering if there is anyway to directly view a parent document using `path`? For example, for any path in a subcollection, I would want to do the following:

```
match /myRootCollection/{myRootDoc=**} {
        allow write: if request.path.split('/')[0] === "myRootDoc1":
}
```

I understand I can also just have the reference of `myRootDoc1` in the subcollection's documents as so:

```
{
        myRootCollection: {
                {myRootDoc1}: {
                        mySubCollection: {
                                {mySubCollectionDoc1}: {
                                        name: "someUser0",
                                        parent: "myRootDoc1",
                                },
                                {mySubCollectionDoc2}: {
                                        name: "someUser1",
                                        parent: "myRootDoc1",
                                },
                                {mySubCollectionDoc3}: {
                                        name: "someUser2",
                                        parent: "myRootDoc1",
                                },

                        }
                {myRootDoc2}: {
                        mySubCollection: {
                                {mySubCollectionDoc1}: {
                                        name: "someUser3",
                                        parent: "myRootDoc2",
                                },
                                {mySubCollectionDoc2}: {
                                        name: "someUser4",
                                        parent: "myRootDoc2",
                                },
                                {mySubCollectionDoc3}: {
                                        name: "someUser5",
                                        parent: "myRootDoc2",
                                },

                        }
                }
                
                
                
        }
}
```

Here, I would be able to read the `mySubCollectionDocs` if they are under a specific parent. The above works because I have the field directly in each doc, but is it possible to just read a `mySubCollectionDoc` and get its parent using path from Firestore Security without the specified field?

If I am able to, how would I able to query using node.js (as Firebase protects against any potential leaky queries)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
match /myRootCollection/{myRootDoc}/mySubCollection/{id} {
   allow write: if myRootDoc == "xxx";
}
```